# can't update read-only /usr

Tags: apt, readonly, software-updates

Got `/usr` in a separate logic partition (LVM).

If `sudo apt-get update` throws error "read-only".

There's a way to keep it `ro` but allowing updates, or switching between ro and rw?

Comment: Not possible, updating means writing  to disk so you cannot update a system without writing to it !

Comment: There's a way to configure a "switch"? ie: a script for use when updating, then switch back to `ro`.

Comment: If you want to keep things like `/usr` read-only, you should look into "atomic distributions" like [CoreOS](https://getfedora.org/coreos/) or [Ubuntu Core](https://core.docs.ubuntu.com/en/guides/intro/what-is-core).

Comment: This question fills by head with ideas, only I don't exactly know what they are. It needs some more clarity: What are you asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dpkg` hooks to remount `/usr` as necessary. If you always use `apt`, add this to your `apt` configuration:

```
DPkg {
    // Auto re-mounting of a readonly /usr
    Pre-Invoke {"mount -o remount,rw /usr";};
    Post-Invoke {"mount -o remount,ro /usr";};
}
```

There is at least one caveat: the read-only remount will fail if the `dpkg` invocations result in any files remaining in use after being deleted. There are various workarounds for this: you can [restart the affected processes](https://wiki.debian.org/ReadonlyRoot#Find_processes_blocking_the_remount_readonly), or [keep a copy of deleted files and clean them up on reboot](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2001/11/msg00212.html).

Comment: actually I was using `chmod -R 666 /usr` and then back to 444. Is a good approach?

Comment: That’s a rather dangerous approach; most if not all files and directories under `/usr` have permissions other than 666. Furthermore, 444 doesn’t prevent root from writing...

Comment: thx now I see. what idk is if `/usr` + `ro` will cause programs to not work.

Comment: about restarting affected processes, got `needrestart` package, should it work?

Comment: Read-only `/usr` works fine, programs don’t need to write there — files which are supposed to be written go in `/var` or in `/home`. `needrestart` should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have had systems configured with read-only `/`, with `/home` and `/var` on a separate RW drive. The workflow for updates was:

```
# mount -o remount,rw /
# [package manager command goes here]
# mount -o remount,ro /
```

In your case, you'd be remounting `/usr` rather than `/` but the general concept is entirely identical

Comment: i've did it. And used `chmod -R 666 /usr` too. In both cases when I go **Thunar** and check /usr folder properties nothing has changed on permissions tag, even refreshing window. Any idea?

Comment: what? "`chmod -R 666 /usr`" is a very bad idea

Comment: why, it should work isn't it?

Comment: it removes execute permissions from everything in there

Comment: must be read and execute & read and write, right?

Comment: ideally the permissions would be, whatever they were before you did that. assuming they're in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/sbin`, you've also inadvertently removed suid on sudo and su as well

Comment: Your command seems to be dangerous. If use it could break the system.

Comment: remounting filesystems won't break the system. your unprompted attempt at changing permissions across a system directory is system-breaking

Comment: for clarification: nothing here involves file-permissions. the permission system is entirely separate and should not be changed from the defaults. the partition itself should be mounted either read-write or read-only

Comment: The only I know is that after using your command my system just crashed, and while reboot now boots only with sh CLI. So now I must use recovery mode.

Comment: your chmod command is almost certainly what caused that crash. removing execute permission from all of `/usr` tells executables not to be runnable and shared libraries not to be loadable

Comment: But used it one session user, one session root and then another session user. In that last session used the command u shared, and it crashed. I can just speculate. Then how should repair this now?

Comment: do you keep backups? restoring the permissions to their sane defaults should probably be your first line of action

Comment: Reinstalled the system and used the command `mount`. It worked, maybe it crashed while combined both, excuse me for the misunderstood and thank you.